# Is the any way to make the window.onload function execute only one time?

Tags: jquery, return-value

I have a `window.onload` function, which loads an AJAX content. It fires also when the visitor is viewing another page and try to reload it (which is also called with AJAX by the way).  The `window.onload` function executes again.

Is the any way to make the `window.onload` function execute only one time (by storing in cache or something)?

Comment: Use cookies or sessions?

Answer (score 3):

You could set a cookie when the AJAX has completed, and then check for this cookie when loading the page. Some pseudo code:

```
$(function() {
    if (!$.cookie("page-viewed")) {
        // call ajax & display

        $.cookie("page-viewed", true);
    }
});
```

Here's a link to the [jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

---

**Update**

Based on the code in your comment, you would use the cookie plugin like this:

```
$(window).load(function() { 
    if (!$.cookie("page-viewed")) {
        $('#pages_holder').hide(0).delay(2500).fadeIn(1200, 'swing', {queue:false}); 
        $('#za').rotate3Di('+=360', 1000, {queue:false}, 'easeInOutCubic'); 
        $('.za').show().switchClass("za", "nas",500, 'easeOutQuad').switchClass("nas", "zavur6en", 1250, 'easeInOutCubic').delay(2000).hide(0) 
        $.ajax({ 
            url : 'pages/zanas.php', 
            success : function(response) { 
                $("#pages").html(response); 
            } 
        }); 
        $.cookie("page-viewed", true);
    }
});
```

Comment: I have never used cookies man. If that is my code what do i need to do:

'
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#pages_holder').hide(0).delay(2500).fadeIn(1200, 'swing', {queue:false});
 
    $('#za').rotate3Di('+=360', 1000, {queue:false}, 'easeInOutCubic'); 
 $('.za').show().switchClass("za", "nas",500, 'easeOutQuad').switchClass("nas", "zavur6en", 1250, 'easeInOutCubic').delay(2000).hide(0)
 
     $.ajax({
      url : 'pages/zanas.php',
      success : function(response) {
       $("#pages").html(response); 
      }
     });
  

});
'

Comment: God bless you man, but i tried this before and the animation does not execute. You can see it here: http://lambev-design.com - nothing happens. (The code is in the "moves.js" file.)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        // Have your onload ajax here
    });
</script>
```

I've never seen this runned more then once per page load.

Comment: But this will still execute on every page load?

Comment: Well duh :P when a page is loaded through navigation or f5, this script is runned.

Comment: Exactly. The OP only want it to run once. Successive loads - either by URL bar or F5 should not run the script.